# How do I create a wiki index?

Tags: sharepoint-server, wiki

My group uses SharePoint Server 2013 and has a set of wiki pages we use to allow team members to easily share knowledge with each other. While it's a nice resource, it's hard to find what you're looking for as you're reduced to entering search terms and hoping that you use the same type of terminology a page author used. To solve this, I'd like to use some sort of site index page that automatically updates. For example, it could list all keywords used in the wiki pages and then allow users to browse pages by keyword and/or category.

I'm a newbie to SharePoint and after doing a lot of searching (both on this site and on Google) I am not sure how to achieve this. Could it be that my group's "wiki site" was not created "properly" or that I just don't have the right permissions to find the tools I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Wiki pages exist in a library, so perhaps add a field for "category" and mark it as required. Of course, this means that all pages will need to be updated to assign a category. Then, you could create custom views of the wiki page library to view them by category.